# Please display user's local time when I hover the mouse over their icon

Tags: feature-request, chat, internationalization

I'm always curious what time it is for other people in the chat room.  Yes, I suppose I could ask them ... but I wish that, when I hovered my mouse over their icon (or clicked on it) I'd see any of

- their time zone
- their local time when they said the message to the right of my mouse
- their local time now

Comment: I don't believe the user's local time is ever sent to the server in any form, so there's no way to display that information to other users.

Comment: What time zone they live in is their private information. If they don't want to share it with you...

Comment: Terrible idea - if you need to know, ask them. If they want to share, they'll tell you.

Answer (score 1):

No. We should not be able to access this personal piece of information from the user. For curiosity, you should ask them instead of just demanding all of this as mandatory while some users don't want to.

You can certainly know when they posted their comment, but in your time zone. Users don't need others just grabbing personal information from them. Privacy is highly respected here at SE, so clearly this request will be denied: [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)... We can certainly do [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)-ish if you want users to be able to ask what time it is in their area.

So hopefully: [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)